# Compare two CSV file using PowerShell and return matching values faster

Tags: performance, powershell, csv

I use this code for matching two CSV file and get the columns i need
in this code i compare the data `Matricule` `name` and `Firstname` and when I get a match I can retrieve the column 'IGG'

But it is very slow... (20min for 18 lines)

Someone can help me with this ?

Here is my code :

```
foreach ($item in $fileContentIMM) 
{
    try
    {
        $Matricule = $item.'Matricule'
        $name = $item.'Nom'
        $firstname = $item.'Prenom'

        # find first matching row in $$fileContentMagic using wildcard
        $objMatch = $fileContentMagic | where { $_.'Matricule' -eq $Matricule -and $_.'NOM' -eq $name -and $_.'PRENOM' -eq $firstname}


        ##### check if any match found 
        if ($objMatch -eq $null)
        {
            $item  | ForEach-Object {
                $filechecktrue += [pscustomobject]@{
                    'MATRICULE' = $item.'Matricule'
                    'IGG' = 'noSet'
                    'NAME'  = $item.'Nom'
                    'FIRSTNAME' = $item.'Prenom'
                    'SERVICE' = $item.'Service'
                    'Immeuble'= $item.'Immeuble' 
                    'Niveau' = $item.'Niveau'
                    'Loc.' = $item.'Loc.'
                    'PDT' = $item.'PDT'
                    'Occ.' = $item.'Occ.'
                    'Site' = $item.'Site'
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $item  | ForEach-Object {
                $filechecktrue += [pscustomobject]@{
                    'MATRICULE' = $item.'Matricule'
                    'IGG' = ($objMatch.'IGG' -join '/')
                    'NAME'  = $item.'Nom'
                    'FIRSTNAME' = $item.'Prenom'
                    'SERVICE' = $item.'Service'
                    'Immeuble'= $item.'Immeuble' 
                    'Niveau' = $item.'Niveau'
                    'Loc.' = $item.'Loc.'
                    'PDT' = $item.'PDT'
                    'Occ.' = $item.'Occ.'
                    'Site' = $item.'Site'
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        "ERROR: Problem reading line - skipping :" | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
        $item.nom + $item.prenom + $item.service| Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: 20 minutes to find 18 lines out of how many? Have you looked at `Compare-Object`?

Comment: Are you sure this is the slow part? How large are the two csv-files? Have you measured or used ex. `Write-Host "import done"` to determine that it's not reading of the file that is slow?

Comment: the file contentIMM contain 18 lines and the filecontentMagic 45000

Comment: maybe i'm gonna check thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would read the file you're using for lookups and then create a HashTable for that.  HashTables are very efficient for doing lookups.

Try something like this, assuming you don't have any duplicates in in `FileContentMagic`:

```
# Use any character here which is guaranteed not to be present in the Matricule, Nom,
# or Prenom fields
$Delimiter = '|'

# Read the FileContent Magic into a HashTable for fast lookups
# The key is Matricule|Nom|Prenom
# The value is IGG joined with a forward slash
$FileContentMagic = @{}
Import-Csv -Path $FileContentMagicFileName | ForEach-Object {
    # Here we build our lookup key. The Trim() is just in case there's any leading or trailing
    # whitespace You can leave it out if you know you don't need it
    $Key = $_.Matricule.Trim(), $_.Nom.Trim(), $_.Prenom.Trim() -join $Delimiter

    # Since we only need the IGG value joined with a /, we'll just keep that
    $Value = $_.IGG -join '/'
    $FileContentMagic.Add($Key, $Value)
}

$FileContentIMM = Import-Csv -Path $FileContentIMMFileName

$FileCheckTrue = foreach ($item in $FileContentIMM) {
    $Key = $_.Matricule.Trim(), $_.Nom.Trim(), $_.Prenom.Trim() -join $Delimiter

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'MATRICULE' = $item.'Matricule'
        'IGG'       = if ($FileContentMagic.ContainsKey($Key)) { $FileContentMagic[$Key] } else { 'noSet' }
        'NAME'      = $item.'Nom'
        'FIRSTNAME' = $item.'Prenom'
        'SERVICE'   = $item.'Service'
        'Immeuble'  = $item.'Immeuble' 
        'Niveau'    = $item.'Niveau'
        'Loc.'      = $item.'Loc.'
        'PDT'       = $item.'PDT'
        'Occ.'      = $item.'Occ.'
        'Site'      = $item.'Site'
    }
}
```

Also, any time you're using `+=` to concatenate an array, you're introducing a significant performance penalty. It's worth it to avoid using it because each assignment creates a new array, copies the entire array over with the new item, and then discards the old array. It's very inefficient.

If `$FileContentMagic` contains duplicate keys, then you should change how the HashTable is loaded to:

```
$FileContentMagic = @{}
Import-Csv -Path $FileContentMagicFileName | ForEach-Object {
    $Key = $_.Matricule.Trim(), $_.Nom.Trim(), $_.Prenom.Trim() -join $Delimiter
    if (!$FileContentMagic.ContainsKey($Key)) {
        $Value = $_.IGG -join '/'
        $FileContentMagic.Add($Key, $Value)
    }
    else {
        $FileContentMagic[$Key] += '/' + ($_.IGG -join '/')
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i try this and i divided the time by 3 !but if i need more values than 'IGG' how can i do it ?

Comment: Change to `$Value = $_` and update the rest to access the igg-property from the returned object from the hashtable. This is a simple change you should be able to fix yourself. I wouldn't recommend running code you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify this, but the changes shouldn't affect the time to process much. The only optimization I've done is changed $filechecktrue to a List which is more memory-efficient.

Not sure if this is actually the slow part of your script. That would require `$fileContentMagic` to be a VERY large array.

```
$filechecktrue = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($item in $fileContentIMM) 
{
    try
    {
        $Matricule = $item.'Matricule'
        $name = $item.'Nom'
        $firstname = $item.'Prenom'

        # find first matching row in $fileContentMagic using wildcard
        $objMatch = $fileContentMagic | Where-Object { $_.'Matricule' -eq $Matricule -and $_.'NOM' -eq $name -and $_.'PRENOM' -eq $firstname}

        #Create results object with common properties
        $o += [pscustomobject]@{
            'MATRICULE' = $item.'Matricule'
            'IGG' = 'noSet'
            'NAME'  = $item.'Nom'
            'FIRSTNAME' = $item.'Prenom'
            'SERVICE' = $item.'Service'
            'Immeuble'= $item.'Immeuble' 
            'Niveau' = $item.'Niveau'
            'Loc.' = $item.'Loc.'
            'PDT' = $item.'PDT'
            'Occ.' = $item.'Occ.'
            'Site' = $item.'Site'
        }

        ##### check if any match found 
        if ($objMatch)
        {
            #if not null, set IGG value. No need for foreach as $item is already a "foreach-value".
            $o.IGG = ($objMatch.'IGG' -join '/')
        }

        #Add result to arraylist
        $filechecktrue.Add($o)
    }
    catch
    {
        "ERROR: Problem reading line - skipping :" | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
        $item.nom + $item.prenom + $item.service| Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: yep this didn't affect the time to process thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your first foreach returns a single $item-object on every iteration, so it's nonsense to again use a foreach on $item inside the code block (twice).

Try this (redundancy removed):

```
foreach ($item in $fileContentIMM) {
    try {
        # find first matching row in $fileContentMagic using wildcard
        $objMatch = $fileContentMagic | where { $_.'Matricule' eq $item.'Matricule'
                                           -and $_.'NOM' -eq $item.'Nom'
                                           -and $_.'PRENOM' -eq $item.'Prenom'}


        ##### check if any match found 
        if ($objMatch -eq $null) {
            $IGG = 'noSet'
        } else {
            $IGG = ($objMatch.'IGG' -join '/')
        }
        $filechecktrue += [pscustomobject]@{
            'MATRICULE' = $item.'Matricule'
            'IGG' = $IGG
            'NAME'  = $item.'Nom'
            'FIRSTNAME' = $item.'Prenom'
            'SERVICE' = $item.'Service'
            'Immeuble'= $item.'Immeuble' 
            'Niveau' = $item.'Niveau'
            'Loc.' = $item.'Loc.'
            'PDT' = $item.'PDT'
            'Occ.' = $item.'Occ.'
            'Site' = $item.'Site'

    } catch {
        "ERROR: Problem reading line - skipping :" | Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
        $item.nom + $item.prenom + $item.service| Out-File $LogFile -Append -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: yep i save only a few seconds but you are right thanks :)